# ¿Cómo solucionar problemas de W3C?

Tags: html

¿Cómo puedo solucionar estos dos problemas? He buscado por Internet y no encontré gran cosa, si alguien me puede ayudar...

> Error: Bad value tel: +3400000000 for attribute href on element a: Illegal character in scheme data: space is not allowed.
>
> From line 68, column 43; to line 68, column 70
>
> ils_menu">

Y este:

> Error: Element a not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
>
> From line 81, column 10; to line 81, column 25
>
> ↩
>
> HO
>
> Contexts in which element a may be used:
>
> Where phrasing content is expected.
>
> Content model for element ul:
>
> Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Primer caso**

Si en el href quieres poner un espacio, no lo pongas literalmente, sino que puedes poner "%20".

En tu caso quedaría:

```
<a href="tel:%20+3400000000">
```

**Segundo caso**

No puedes poner un `<a>` dentro de un `<ul>`, sino que tienes que incluirlo dentro de un `<li>`.

Por ejemplo, esto es **erroneo**

```
<ul>
     <a href="http://google.com">Enlace</a>
     <li>Lo que sea</li>
</ul>
```

Esto es **correcto**

```
<ul>
     <li>
        <a href="http://google.com">Enlace</a>
     </li>
     <li>Lo que sea</li>
</ul>
```

un saludo.

Comment: y si quiero que todo el li sea un link no solo el texto como lo soluciono?

Comment: Que problema hay en poner <li><a href="http://google.com">Ir a Google</a></li>?? La palabra "Ir a Google" (que es el único texto que hay en el li) será un enlace, exceptuando el icono del li.

Comment: no ninguno pero se puede hacer de alguna manera que te coja todo el li como link o eso no se hace con los li

Comment: el alt con php tampoco lo coje? Error: An img element must have an alt attribute, except under certain conditions. For details, consult guidance on providing text alternatives for images.

From line 193, column 7; to line 193, column 44

-->↩      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">↩ este es el codigo php alt="<?php echo $foto->titulo; ?>"

Comment: Creo que te confundes con "title" ;)

Comment: Error: An img element must have an alt attribute, except under certain conditions. For details, consult guidance on providing text alternatives for images. From line 193, column 7; to line 193, column 44 -->↩ <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

Comment: dice del alt no title

Comment: Disculpa. Bueno, lo que dice está claro, que el <img> necesita tener un atributo "alt" sí o sí. Como estás creando el tag <img>? Es así? <img class="modal-content" id="img01" alt="<?php echo $foto->titulo; ?>">

Comment: adjunto el codigo entero:   <div class="galerie_foto"><img class="myImg" src="image/galerie/<?php echo $foto->img; ?>" alt="<?php echo $foto->titulo; ?>"><br><?php echo $foto->titulo; ?></div>